# ValueError: Shapes (1, 107, 3) and (1, 107, 2) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have such a  problem, and it happened on the latest version of tensorflow. I hope somebody can give me some suggestions.
my code as below:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import h5py
import t3f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filename = "./video.h5"
np.random.seed(0)
with h5py.File(filename, "r") as f:
    print("Keys: %s" % f.keys())
    a_group_key = list(f.keys())[0]
    data = list(f[a_group_key])
    data_np = np.array(data)
data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_np)
shape = [107]+[60]+[80]+[3]
# A is large tt-ranks tensor
A = t3f.to_tt_tensor(data_tensor)
# Create an X variable.
init_X = t3f.random_tensor(shape, tt_rank=3)
X = t3f.get_variable('X', initializer=init_X)
def step():
    gradF = X - A
    riemannian_grad = t3f.riemannian.project(gradF, X)
    alpha = 1.0
    t3f.assign(X, t3f.round(X - alpha * riemannian_grad, max_tt_rank=2))
    return 0.5 * t3f.frobenius_norm_squared(X - A)
log = []
for i in range(1000):
    F = step()
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(F)
    log.append(F.numpy())
```

Exit:

> ---
>
> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
> 1 log = []
> 2 for i in range(1000):
> ----> 3     F = step()
> 4     if i % 10 == 0:
> 5         print(F)
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py
> in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)    1115     """    1116
> if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
> -> 1117       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))    1118     1119   def
> most_specific_compatible_shape(self, other):
>
> ValueError: Shapes (1, 107, 3) and (1, 107, 2) are incompatible

But the data_tensor's shape is [107]+[60]+[80]+[3], it's same with A or X, I'm confused.

I runned this code on google colab with tf2 and python3.6.
In this link you would recurrence my question [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Qz-TBBAbnflKioPn-YxxFwl59K3DVlWb?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue! It's caused by the rank be different between tensor.So,I modified one of tensor rank in order to match another.